# bootstrap two row navbar (links in top row toggle navbar in bottom row), button between rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $('.collapse').not(this).removeClass('in');
});

$('[data-toggle=collapse]').click(function (e) {
  $('[data-toggle=collapse]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
header {
 background-color:#3e3e3e;
}
header .logodesc img {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
header .btn-prihlasit-cont{
 padding-top:34px;
}
header .prihlasit {
 padding: 7px 14px 7px 16px;
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #F2F2F2;
 min-width: 210px;
}
.navbar {margin-bottom:0;}
.navbar-inverse{
 background-color:#3e3e3e;
 border:none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
 color:#fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
 border-color:transparent;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:active, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
 color:#626262;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
 color:#626262;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
 color:#fff;
}
#topmenu {
 border-bottom:solid 1px #626262;
 border-radius:0;
}
#topmenu .dropdown, #topmenu .dropup{
 background: url(../img/dropdbg.png) top right no-repeat;
}
#topmenu > ul > li:nth-child(2){
 background: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) { /* XS */
 .nav{width:100%;}
 .navbar-brand-centered {
        display: inline-block;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin:0;
        float:none;
    }

    .navbar-header{
        text-align:center;
    }
 #topmenu .dropdown, #topmenu .dropup{
  background:none;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Two rows navbar</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
  <a class="logodesc" href="#">
                <img alt="logo" width="155" height="52" src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 paddR0">
  <div class="navbar-header navbar-inverse hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
            <button class = "navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-links-collapse">
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-logo-collapse">
                <img alt="logo" width="100" height="31" src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <a class = "navbar-toggle pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-search-collapse">

            </a>

  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="topmenu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown active">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#two">Two</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="submenu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-inverse collapse in" id="one">
      <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 4</a></li>
   <li><a class = "navbar-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-search-collapse"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-inverse collapse" id="two">
      <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 3</a></li>
   <li><a class = "navbar-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-search-collapse"></a>
   <form class="nav navbar-form" role="search" id="nav-header-search-collapse">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
   </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs paddL0 btn-prihlasit-cont">
 <a href="#" class="btn prihlasit">Send a friend</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

I need a such two rows navbar (bootstrap 3).
When I click on first link in top navbar(Nav-A-1) - in bottom navbar I see a first list of links (Nav-B-1  Nav-B-2 Nav-B-3 etc). When I click on second link in top navbar(Nav-A-2) - I see the second list of links in bottom navbar (Nav-C-1  Nav-C-2 Nav-C-3 etc). It is like a tabs. The first "tab" mast be active.

LG, MD, SM
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| . . . . . . . . . . .|  Nav-A-1 . . .  Nav-A-2 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .|
|  SITE LOGO    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| Button |--+
| . . . . . . . . . . .|  Nav-B-1 . . Nav-B-2 . . Nav-B-3 . . Nav-B-4 . . Search_icon . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
XS
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| . . . . . . . . . . . . | . . . . . . . . . . | .  . . .  . . . . . . .|
| . Hamburger . .|  SITE LOGO  |   Search_icon  |
| . . . . . . . . . . . . | . . . . . . . . . . | . . . .   . . . . . . .|
+---------------------------------------------------------+

Comment: super confusing, can you please make it simple.

Comment: What is the difference between `Nav-A-*` and `Nav-B-*`?

Comment: Have some problems with formatting, sorry )

Comment: maybe show what you are trying to do in jsfiddle or some screenshots?

Comment: I found this https://www.bootply.com/Axbt2Y0LIQ
So I need a logo in left, and button between top and bottom rows.

But how I can take a XS-mode (hamburger - logo - search icon)?

Comment: What I got, you can see in the snippet. There are a couple of questions left. How can I make the menu collapsed? How do I show the search form when I click on the search icons (at the top and in the submenu)?

When you click the links in the top menu again, the bottom menu disappears. How to remove this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I use nav-pills, without javascript!

```css
header {
 background-color:#3e3e3e;
}
header .logodesc img {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
header .btn-prihlasit-cont{
 padding-top:22px;
}
header .prihlasit {
 padding: 7px 14px 7px 16px;
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #F2F2F2;
 min-width: 210px;
}
.navbar {margin-bottom:0;}
.navbar-inverse{
 background-color:#3e3e3e;
 border:none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a, .navbar-nav>li>a {
 color:#fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
 border-color:transparent;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:active, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
 color:#626262;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
 color:#626262;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover {
 background-color: transparent;
 color:#fff;
}
#nav-header-links-collapse{
 width:100%;
}
.nav-pills {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #626262;
}
.nav-pills>li>a {
 color:#626262;
}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover{
 color:#fff;
 background-color: #000;
 border-radius:0;
}
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover{
 border-radius:0;
 background-color: transparent;
}
a.navbar-toggle.glyphicon.glyphicon-search {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Promotional Columns - Bootsnipp.com</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" >
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <!--navbar -->
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
  <a class="logodesc" href="#">
                <img alt="logo" width="155" height="52" src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 paddR0">
  <div class="navbar-header navbar-inverse hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
            <button class = "navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-links-collapse">
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-logo-collapse">
                <img alt="logo" width="100" height="31" src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            <a class = "navbar-toggle pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-search-collapse">

            </a>

  </div>
  <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav-header-links-collapse">
  <ul  class="nav nav-pills">
   <li class="active">
        <a  href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Using nav-pills</a>
   </li>
   
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-inverse collapse in" id="one">
     <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 4</a></li>
     <li class="hidden-xs"><a class = "navbar-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-search-collapse"></a></li>
    </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-inverse collapse in" id="two">
     <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 11</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 12</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 13</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 14</a></li>
     <li class="hidden-xs"><a class = "navbar-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-search" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#nav-header-search-collapse"></a></li>
    </ul>
     </div>

        
  </div>
  </div>
                <form class="nav navbar-form collapse" role="search" id="nav-header-search-collapse">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 hidden-xs paddL0 btn-prihlasit-cont">
 <a href="#" class="btn prihlasit">Send a friend</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--navbar -->
 
</header>
```